# .NET and C++ interoperability

Tags: c++, .net, interop

I'm having a C++ dll which has an exported function having the following signature...

```
__declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
 void Paint(LPDISPATCH& disp, VARIANT& x, VARIANT& y, VARIANT& z);
```

I want to call the this exported function from C#.NET. For this is used the following prototype...

```
[DllImport("xyz.dll", 
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)
public static extern void Paint(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch), In, Out] ref object which,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4), In, Out] ref object x,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4), In, Out] ref object y,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4), In, Out] ref object x);
```

When i tried to invoke the call, it is throwing an exception saying that Attempted to read/write memory which is invalid.

Please advise me on this, on how to P/invoke this C++ API from .NET.

> Much Thanks, Sundareswaran Senthilvel

Comment: Part of the problem may be in how you are calling the method, can you show some code that attempts to call the method from .Net.

Answer (score 1):

You have different return types, it is declared to return `void`, but you import it with `bool`.

Comment: Yeah now it is corrected, please provide me an answer for my problem.